# Are there any good design pattern cookbook / recipe resources?

Tags: design-patterns, resources, cookbook

i know there are tons of books out there for design patterns in almost any programming language.

and most of them will go through some examples to show you what can be done.

but i'm thinking along the lines of recipe / cookbook type, are there any good resources to learn via this way?

i.e. something like problem - solution kind of methodology.

it could be a book, source codes, web sites or anything.

are there any?

[something like this for example.](http://patterncookbook.blogspot.sg/)

it would be sweeter if it's in C# though :)

thanks

Comment: you tube you can find out more videos. That is enough. If  u need more info, oodesign.com will help you. but none of the site will tell you, which will suit for you. you need to think and opt best design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make use of these two sites:

[dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) and 
 [Source making](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second link looks promising.